# Calling Ansible variables inside Shell script

Tags: shell-script, ansible

I have inventory file as below,

```
[routers]
iLAB-SR-12-R2 ansible_host=192.168.82.211
iLAB-SR-12-R3 ansible_host=192.168.82.212
iLAB-SR-12-R4 ansible_host=192.168.82.213
```

And I have shell script for comparing multiple files with master file,

```
#!/bin/bash
config_location="/etc/ansible/test"
master="/etc/ansible/test-master"
cd $config_location
file=`ls -l | grep "^-" | awk '{print $NF}'`
echo "Hostname      IpAddress      Comments" > /etc/ansible/output.csv
for i in $file
do
  if diff -c $i $master > "/etc/ansible/test-difference/diff_$i" ;then
    echo "$i                    NoChange"
  else
    echo "$i                    SomeChange"
  fi
done >> /etc/ansible/output.csv
```

The question is if it was ansible i would use {{remote_host}} to get the ipaddress for my output.csv file. In script how could i call variable {{ansible_host}} to get ipaddress or is there any way.

Below is my sample output.csv file but the ipaddress is empty now,

```
Hostname   Ipaddress   Comments
Test1                   Somechanges
Test2                   Nochanges
```

Anyone help me how to get the ipaddress from the inventory file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way you are assigning your `file`-variable will fail you sooner or later.  [You should not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) , and I suggest naming the variable something other than "file", because `file` is a command name.  You should quote your variables, too.  File names can have spaces in them...

Comment: You are echoing a files name, not its contents.  So there can't be any IP-Adresses, unless you happen to have files named like IP-Adresses.

Comment: Why are you using ansible as a data source and then reinventing its functionality?  Do that logic in ansible and you can just interpolate variables.   Im nort sure i understand what you're actually trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Seconded. `ansible -i inventoryfile all -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'` will get you your ip-adresses.

Answer (score 3):

Can you modify your script ?

If you can, at the start of the script get the two parameters you need like:

```
remote_host="$1"
ansible_host="$2"
```

Then in your playbook, you can call your script this way:

```
myscript {{remote_host}} {{ansible_host}}
```

It's been a long time since I played with ansible. Make sure the syntax is right :)

Comment: Julien, Let me try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @riswan66 sure :) Don't hesitate to edit my post in case I made a syntax error :)

Comment: Julien, 
If we call the variable as you mentioned means its getting the variable name but if we use with echo it doesnot print all the ipaddress instead print the 1 ipaddress repeated times. See below example,
```
ansible_host="$1"
echo "Hostname      IpAddress      Comments" > /etc/ansible/output.csv
for i in $file
do
  if diff -c $i $master > "/etc/ansible/test-difference/diff_$i" ;then
    echo "$i       $ansible_host             NoChange"
  else
    echo "$i        $ansible_host            SomeChange"
  fi
done >> /etc/ansible/output.csv
```

Comment: The output we want is,
Hostname            Ipaddress            Comments
iLAB-SR-12-R2   192.168.82.211    NoChange
iLAB-SR-12-R3   192.168.82.212    SomeChange

But the output we get is,
Hostname            Ipaddress            Comments
iLAB-SR-12-R2   192.168.82.211    NoChange
iLAB-SR-12-R3   192.168.82.211    SomeChange

Means it reading the variables but cannot all the values.
Script Execution:
./test.sh {{ansible_host}}

Comment: @riswan66 Hum... from your comment, expected == actual; probably a copy paste issue, can you check that ?^^